# Adding resources with jwt_required?

Tags: python, flask, jwt, flask-restful

I've created an API using flask, where the authentication is all working fine using flask_jwt_extended.

However if I add a resource that has a jwt_required decorator I get this error.

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_jwt/__init__.py", line 176, in decorator
    _jwt_required(realm or current_app.config['JWT_DEFAULT_REALM'])
KeyError: 'JWT_DEFAULT_REALM'
```

Example resource:

```
class Endpoint(Resource):

    @jwt_required()
    def get(self):
        return {"State": "Success"}
```

Initialising the app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
```

Adding the resource:

```
api.add_resource(resource_class, "/myEndpoint")
```

The only way I can get it to work is to define the Endpoint class in the same file as the API.

I think I need someway to pass the Realm into the endpoint class and have use the optional parameter on jwt_required to set the Realm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discovered the issue, in the resource I was importing the `jwt_required`:

```
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required
```

However I needed to `import jwt_required` from the class that where JWT was initalized.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean circular dependency, what if you are using Blue Prints

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot to initialize [JWT](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/#quickstart) instance. You can do it in 2 ways. **First**:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_jwt import jwt_required, JWT
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

class Endpoint(Resource):

    @jwt_required()
    def get(self):
        return {"State": "Success"}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'

def authenticate(username, password):
    # you should find user in db here
    # you can see example in docs
    user = None
    if user:
        # do something
        return user

def identity(payload):
    # custom processing. the same as authenticate. see example in docs
    user_id = payload['identity']
    return None
# here what you need
jwt = JWT(app, authenticate, identity)
api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(Endpoint, '/myEndpoint')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**The second way** is update our configuration of application. Just change:

```
jwt = JWT(app, authenticate, identity)
```

To:

```
app.config.update(
     JWT=JWT(app, authenticate, identity)
)
```

Let's open our route. You will see:

```
{
  "description": "Request does not contain an access token", 
  "error": "Authorization Required", 
  "status_code": 401
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Danila, JWT was initialized, I didn't show it in my sample.